# android webapps are simple native app or just web links

Tags: android

A webapp is a simple native app that use webview and can be downloaded in mobile sets or completely access by url without any downloading/installing as app, and use as url link icon?

rgds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webapp is usually classified as a website that the user would "Add to the Home Screen" and wouldn't require a download/install from an app store.

A "wrapper" is usually a webapp wrapped in a webView that way it can be made into an APK and uploaded to an app store. This becomes a native application.

Here's a good read on the topic: http://mobithinking.com/native-or-web-app/